# Download file from Amazon S3 using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hapi.js

I have my own `REST API` to call in order to **download** a file. *(At the end, the file could be store in different kind of server... Amazon s3, locally etc...)*

To get a file from s3, I should use this method:

```
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

This will give me a downloadable link to call.

Now, my question is, how can I use my own rest API to download a file when it comes from that link? Is there a way to redirect the call?

I'm using `Hapi` for my **REST** server.

```
{
    method: "GET", path: "/downloadFile",
    config: {auth: false},
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        // TODO
        reply({})
    }
},
```

Comment: Why do you need the link to then call that link to download the file, why not just download the file and return the stream?

Comment: @peteb Wouldn't that make the file be downloaded 2 times for one request? Client will have to wait until the file is downloaded from the server, then stream to him?

Comment: not if you return the stream back to the requester. Think about it like this, you can get a stream from S3 with the contents of that file, you can then use `pipe()` to pipe the S3 stream directly back to the requester. It is never downloaded to the mediator, instead the mediator is just a go between. Especially if you use the AWS-SDK unbufferedStream.

Comment: How do I setup the Hapi request for that? Do you have an example for me of a pipe request? Thx

Comment: I don't find any method call for an unbuffered stream in s3 javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using a redirect to download the desired file, just return back an unbufferedStream instead from S3. An [`unbufferedStream`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/HttpResponse.html#createUnbufferedStream-property) can be returned from the `HttpResponse` within the `AWS-SDK`. This means there is no need to download the file from S3, then read it in, and then have the requester download the file.

FYI I use this `getObject()` approach with Express and have never used Hapi, however I think that I'm pretty close with the route definition but hopefully it will capture the essence of what I'm trying to achieve.

#### Hapi.js route

```
const getObject = require('./getObject');

{
    method: "GET", path: "/downloadFile",
    config: {auth: false},
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        let key = ''; // get key from request
        let bucket = ''; // get bucket from request

        return getObject(bucket, key)
          .then((response) => {
            reply.statusCode(response.statusCode);

            response.headers.forEach((header) => {
              reply.header(header, response.headers[header]);
            });

            return reply(response.readStream);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // handle err
            reply.statusCode(500);
            return reply('error');
          });
    }
},
```

#### getObject.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3(<your-S3-config>);

module.exports = function getObject(bucket, key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get the file from the bucket
    S3.getObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key
    })
      .on('error', (err) => {            
        return reject(err);
      })
      .on('httpHeaders', (statusCode, headers, response) => {
        // If the Key was found inside Bucket, prepare a response object
        if (statusCode === 200) {
          let responseObject = {
            statusCode: statusCode,
            headers: {
              'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + key
            }
          };

          if (headers['content-type'])
            responseObject.headers['Content-Type'] = headers['content-type'];
          if (headers['content-length'])
            responseObject.headers['Content-Length'] = headers['content-length'];

          responseObject.readStream = response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream();
          return resolve(responseObject);
        }
      })
      .send();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying it right now and I'll let you know :)

Comment: Does this result in the S3 bucket content being streamed "through" his server, or does the requestor end up streaming it direct from S3?

Comment: @MikeGoodwin The content being requested is streamed through the local express server before going to the client, due to the direct `getObject()` usage. If that approach isn't ideal, using a signed URL to sign `getObject()` and returning the URL for the action would be the way to go. In that case, the client would request the Express instance to create an authenticated `getObject()` call but not execute it. That would then be represented as a URL that can be returned to the client for a direct to AWS request. This approach has security and cost effects that you should asses before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

Return a HTTP 303 Redirect with the `Location` header set to the blob's public URL in the S3 bucket.

If your bucket is private then you need to proxy the request instead of performing a redirect, unless your clients also have access to the bucket.

Comment: How do I proxy a request?

Comment: There should be no need to proxy the request.  `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` `Location: https://${signed_url}`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If the S3 bucket is private and/or the OP doesn't want to disclose blob URIs to end-users/consumers.

Comment: This still works for that.  If the bucket is private then a pre-signed URL generated right then and used for the redirect, with a short expiration time, can allow a single user to download the file right now and not later.  Mine are set to 5 seconds. They can know the blob URIs all they like, but 5 seconds from now, it won't do them any good. :)   The expiration time of the pre-signed URL is only checked when the request arrives at S3, so you don't have to finish downloading before it expires, you only have to start downloading before it expires.