# Amazon S3 download a file at client location

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have my application that downloads the file form AWS S3 bucket. I am using below code:

```
public void downloadFileFromS3(String key) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        LOG.info("Start - downloadFileFromS3 for key: {} and bucket name: {}", key, bucketName);
        initAWS();
        final GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
        Download download = transferMgr.download(request, new File("D:\\rohit\\"+key));
        download.waitForCompletion();
}
```

Now, as we see the file destination path at client's end is hardcoded as **D:\rohit**. But, in the real world application when user clicks on **download a file** option, the file gets downloaded directly at client end's download folder.

Could someone please help me with file destination path. I am using **Java & Spring Boot**.

I tried searching on the net and found various solutions on stakeoverflow as well. But, the solutions didn't help:

[Download file from Amazon S3 using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984750/download-file-from-amazon-s3-using-rest-api)

[Javascript to download a file from amazon s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket)

[download a file to particular location in client system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427895/download-a-file-to-particular-location-in-client-system)

Answer (score 1):

Browser Handles the download. I'll give you a example. when you have html that says

```
<!-- Browser will download the file to user configured location instead of opening -->
<a href="http://example.org/mypdf.pdf" download>Download PDF</a>
```

Instead of using a anchor tag to download. you can trigger download when a request is received by following process.

1. Generate a presigned url with content-disposition
2. redirect to that URL

Generate an S3 Presigned URL with content-disposition.

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest req = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key);
ResponseHeaderOverrides overrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
overrides.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"give file name how you want your client to save\"");
req.setResponseHeaders(overrides);
URL url = this.client.generatePresignedUrl(req);
```

now redirect your user to the `url` you generated and let the browser handle the download.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have successfully returned URL back to UI. On click, file is getting downloaded, but my xls file is getting downloaded as file type. I have set the content-type as well. But not able to get the correct file.

Comment: what do you mean by downloaded as file type?
when did you set the content-type? before downloading or before uploading?